# How to use Map in query - Batch Apex

Tags: batch, query

```
 public toInsertOrderBillPriceShares_Batch() { 
   for (AccountContactRelation accountContactRelation : (List<AccountContactRelation>) Trigger.new) {
        String oldRoles = (Trigger.isUpdate) ? ((AccountContactRelation) Trigger.oldMap.get(accountContactRelation.Id)).Roles : null;
        System.debug('Firas : Account contact relation' + accountContactRelation);
        if (accountContactRelation.Roles != null && accountContactRelation.Roles.contains(labelVisibilitePortail) && (Trigger.isInsert ||
                (Trigger.isUpdate && (oldRoles == null || !oldRoles.contains(labelVisibilitePortail))))) {
            if (!accountContactRelationIdsMap.containsKey(accountContactRelation.AccountId)) {
                accountContactRelationIdsMap.put(accountContactRelation.AccountId, new List<Id>());
            }
            accountContactRelationIdsMap.get(accountContactRelation.AccountId).add(accountContactRelation.ContactId);
            Set<Id> setIds = accountContactRelationIdsMap.keySet();
    
        }
        

    }
       }

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id, FAB_AccountBill__c, FAB_AccountOrder__c FROM FAB_Order_Bill_Price__c WHERE FAB_AccountOrder__c IN :accountContactRelationIdsMap.keySet() OR FAB_AccountBill__c IN :accountContactRelationIdsMap.keySet()';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   

}
```

This batch can not pass because my query contain : **KeySet()** , how can i avoid this?
Use case convert apex method into Batch class since the method return too much records

**Method** :

```
 public void addVisibilite() {
    Map<Id, List<Id>> accountContactRelationIdsMap = new Map<Id, List<Id>>();

    for (AccountContactRelation accountContactRelation : (List<AccountContactRelation>) Trigger.new) {
        String oldRoles = (Trigger.isUpdate) ? ((AccountContactRelation) Trigger.oldMap.get(accountContactRelation.Id)).Roles : null;

        if (accountContactRelation.Roles != null && accountContactRelation.Roles.contains(labelVisibilitePortail) && (Trigger.isInsert ||
                (Trigger.isUpdate && (oldRoles == null || !oldRoles.contains(labelVisibilitePortail))))) {
            if (!accountContactRelationIdsMap.containsKey(accountContactRelation.AccountId)) {
                accountContactRelationIdsMap.put(accountContactRelation.AccountId, new List<Id>());
            }
            accountContactRelationIdsMap.get(accountContactRelation.AccountId).add(accountContactRelation.ContactId);
        }
    }

    for (FAB_Order_Bill_Price__c orderBillPrice : [
            SELECT Id, FAB_AccountBill__c, FAB_AccountOrder__c
            FROM FAB_Order_Bill_Price__c
            WHERE FAB_AccountOrder__c IN :accountContactRelationIdsMap.keySet() OR FAB_AccountBill__c IN :accountContactRelationIdsMap.keySet()
    ]) {
        Id curAccountId = (orderBillPrice.FAB_AccountBill__c != null) ? orderBillPrice.FAB_AccountBill__c : orderBillPrice.FAB_AccountOrder__c;
        if (curAccountId != null) {
            for (Id contactId : accountContactRelationIdsMap.get(curAccountId)) {
                toInsertOrderBillPriceShares.add(new FAB_Order_Bill_Price__Share(
                        AccessLevel = 'Edit',
                        ParentId = orderBillPrice.Id,
                        UserOrGroupId = contactUserIds.get(contactId)
                ));
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Please don't edit your question to be completely different from what it originally was. That's not how stack exchange works (and it makes it hard to see how answers are relevant). If you have a new question, you should create a completely new question. You can link to previous questions to help provide context (though including a brief summary and being detailed about which specific thing you're asking for help with is probably better. Each link someone has to click through just makes it easier to abandon answering).

Comment: Alright, enough. There's been way too many cosmetic edits and rollbacks on this question, to the extent that the system flagged it for a rollback war. Please stop editing the question at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this fails is because you are trying to use a complex binding expression. Dynamic SOQL only supports binding variables.

The solution is to simply change start to:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    Set<Id> ids = accountContactRelationIdsMap.keySet();

    String query = 'SELECT Id, FAB_AccountBill__c, FAB_AccountOrder__c FROM FAB_Order_Bill_Price__c WHERE FAB_AccountOrder__c IN :ids OR FAB_AccountBill__c IN :ids';

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

That said, it looks to me like you could replace the dynamic SOQL with static SOQL (i.e. the query in square brackets, rather than in quotes) which would benefit you with being able to use complex binding expressions and compile time validation of the SOQL itself.

PS: Only make classes and methods global if absolutely necessary - i.e. where the class/method must be shared across a namespace boundary.

PPS: You would be far better off breaking the explicit dependency on Trigger context detail, having the necessary values passed in to the batch constructor as parameters. That way you can test this batch outside the context of a trigger.